# Put a textbox inside an image

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to insert a textbox inside an image with a dropdown pin to extend the text area.

What I am trying to replicate is the following textbox: ( https://www.spanishdict.com/ )

[image]

With the image in the background and the text drop down in the foreground.

App:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/street-city-scenery-background_711433-2.jpg"), "My Title")),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Looks good. What do you want more exactly? You say a "dropdown". You wan to select an item when clicking on the box?

Comment: I am trying to overlay the textbox on the image. The "dropdown" part just extends the textbox size - I am trying to replicate that part of the page.

Comment: This is a search bar on the site you linked.

Comment: Yes, its just an example - I want to replace the search bar with a `inputTextBox()`